# Why is VS Code javascript intellisense dependent on the files I have open?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

I have a project using .js and .es6 files (Rails, though I don't think that matters) on which I'm trying to use VS Code's javascript intellisense per [these instructions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript#_javascript-project-jsconfigjson). I have a `jsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "include": [
        "app/assets/javascripts/**/*",
        "vendor/assets/javascripts/**/*"
    ],
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES6",
        "checkJs": true
    }
}
```

at the root and all the javascript is in the folders mentioned in the `include` section. I've also created a `globals.d.ts` file at the root.

If I open `globals.d.ts` in VS Code and then run `Typescript: Restart TS server`, VS Code recognizes those global variables in javascript files. However if I then close  `globals.d.ts` and run `Typescript: Restart TS server` again, VS Code does not recognize the globals. This also happens with global variables created in other javascript files. For example, say `Class.es6` defines a class. I only get intellisense for the class if I have `Class.es6` open in VS Code.

I'm not sure first why my setup isn't working, and second why it would ever depend on which files I have open at the time in VS Code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you explicitly specified `include`, only those included files will be part of your javascript project. You also need to put `global.d.ts` in your `include` if you want it to be picked up

Comment: Wow, definitely should have realized that! Thanks for the tip. I added that to the `include` list though, and nothing has changed. That also doesn't explain the behavior with globals in other javascript files.